# Abelian categories that are not monoidal

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories, abelian-categories

Forgive me if this turns out to be a naive question. I'm quite convinced that not all abelian categories admit (symmetric?) monoidal structure (of course, with the tensor product being additive, meaning that it is an additive bifunctor), but I can't think of an abelian category that doesn't! Maybe I just know of too few abelian categories. Can someone give me an example?

Comment: "Monoidal" is extra structure rather than a property, so it doesn't really make sense to say that an abelian category "is" monoidal. Is what you want an example of an abelian category that *can't be given* the structure of a monoidal category?

Comment: Abelian categories are Cartesian closed, hence symmetric monoidal, but this is a very different monoidal structure to what usual tensor products give.

Comment: @JeremyRickard Yes, I'll fix the question

Comment: @FernandoMuro Abelian categories are never Cartesian closed, since they have a zero object (the only Cartesian closed category with a zero object is $1$).

Comment: @AivazianArshak oops absolutely

Comment: They are non closed symmetric monoidal with the direct sum though

Answer (score 18):

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an additive category with a monoidal structure such that the maps
$$ \otimes \colon \mathcal{A}(A,B)\times\mathcal{A}(C,D) \to
    \mathcal{A}(A\otimes C,B\otimes D)
$$
are biadditive.  Let $U$ be the unit object.  If $n$ is an integer with $n.1_U=0$, it follows (by identifying $A$ with $U\otimes A$) that $n.1_A=0$ for all objects $A$.  From this we see that the abelian category of finite abelian groups admits no monoidal structure.  (Of course the tensor product is commutative and associative, but there is no unit.)

I can't immediately think of an example where the category admits infinite coproducts.  Note that the category of torsion abelian groups is symmetric monoidal under $\text{Tor}(-,-)$, with unit $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$.  (Indeed, for finite abelian $A,B$, a pair of elements $\alpha\in A^*=\text{Hom}(A,\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$ and $\beta\in B^*$ give a map $\text{Tor}(A,B)\xrightarrow{\text{Tor}(\alpha,\beta)}\text{Tor}(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$.  This construction gives a map $A^*\otimes B^*\to \text{Tor}(A,B)^*$, and by adjunction we get a map $\text{Tor}(A,B)\to(A^*\otimes B^*)^*$, which is an isomorphism.  From this point of view it is easy to see that $\text{Tor}(-,-)$ is commutative associative on finite abelian groups, and thus also on the $\text{Ind}$-completion of that category, which is the category of torsion abelian groups.)

Comment: What is the associator for $\operatorname{Tor}$? I can *maybe* convince myself that $\operatorname{Tor}(\operatorname{Tor}(A,B),C)$ and $\operatorname{Tor}(A,\operatorname{Tor}(B,C))$ are pointwise isomorphic, but naturally?

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn I have edited the answer to address this

Comment: Ah, very nice. I guess the point is that Pontryagin duality shows $\mathbf{TorsAb} \simeq \mathbf{ProFinAb}^{\text{op}}$, and the latter has a symmetric monoidal structure given by completed tensor product with unit $\hat{\mathbf Z}$.

Answer (score 18):

In the paper

*Hovey, Mark*, [**Additive closed symmetric monoidal structures on R-modules**](https://arxiv.org/abs/0906.1125), J. Pure Appl. Algebra 215, No. 5, 789-805 (2011). [ZBL1223.18005](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1223.18005).

Hovey shows the following theorem (Theorem 3.3)

> Suppose k is a division ring. If k is not a field, then there is
> no additive closed symmetric monoidal structure on the category of k-modules.
> If k is a field, there is a unique additive closed symmetric monoidal category
> structure on the category of k-modules, up to symmetric monoidal equivalence.

Hovey gives a characterization of such monoidal structures via bimodules by exploting the Eilenberg-Watts theorem. He shows that if R is the unit of an additive closed monoidal category structure on R-Mod then R has to be commutative and is the usual such structure ( Proposition 3.1 ).

Combined with this, a simple dimension argument gives you the proof for the theorem.